# Organization Program of Random Integers

Tags: inequalities, sequences-and-series

Suppose you have an infinite list of distinct positive integers, $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ and you don't know what each $x_i$ is, for any $i$. However, you are allowed to "compare" any two of the integers, which tells you which of the two is bigger (e.g. if you ask to "compare" $x_1$ and $x_2$, you could be told either $x_1\gt x_2$ or $x_2\lt x_1$).

> **Question.** What is the minimum number of "compares" to know for certain that you can put $n$ $x$'s in descending order? (e.g. if
> $n=4$, a possibility could be $x_3\lt x_6\lt x_{12}\lt x_{19}$).

Comment: Here is nothing "random". Do you have taken a look in Knuth: The Art of Computer Programming. Vol. 3 is dedicated to sorting (essentially your question) and searching? This does not mean that this question is unimportant, quite the contrary. It's simply too wide.

Comment: The worst case scenario is still $cn\log n$, only the inequality to prove it is not $2^Q\ge n!$ but $8^Q\ge 2^Q{2Q\choose n}\ge n!$, where $Q$ is the number of queries. The idea is that with $Q$ queries you cannot touch more than $2Q$ numbers, so you can just as well run it on the fixed $2Q$ numbers from the beginning. I'm not sure what @dvitek means by his "randomized" algorithm (unless the idea is that with probability near 1 the new number is outside any finite range, which property, indeed, cannot be used for any legitimate distribution of queries).

Comment: @fedja  Could you guys give me some reading/website ideas to look at to gain more information on this subject.

Comment: @AndrewYang Dieter gave you an excellent reference already. As to the rest, just google "sorting algorithm complexity" and see what matches your level best :-)